# Replacing the value in a column based on a single vectorized condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector, conditional-statements

I tried the following code with multiple conditions and worked perfectly, somehow whatever I am trying with a single condition it won't work. It will simply return the values "1" & "SD" for every row no matter if the value of Col_A is True. Please let me know any suggestions, the weird part is that I am not getting any error whatsoever.

````
condition = [
    df1['Col_A'] == 'TRUE'
]

result1 = ['1']
result2 = ['SD']

df1['Col_B'] = np.select(condition, result1, 'NA')
df1['Col_C'] = np.select(condition, result2, 'NA')
df1```

Input

        Col_A    Col_B     Col_C
    0   TRUE       NA         NA     
    1   FALSE      1001       Valid  
    2   TRUE       NA         NA    
    3   TRUE       NA         NA

Output

        Col_A    Col_B     Col_C
    0   TRUE       NA         NA     
    1   FALSE      NA         NA  
    2   TRUE       NA         NA    
    3   TRUE       NA         NA
  
Desired Output

        Col_A    Col_B     Col_C
    0   TRUE       1         SD     
    1   FALSE      1001      Valid  
    2   TRUE       1         SD    
    3   TRUE       1         SD
````

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data and the expected output

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://akuiper.com/console/8eZjsYa0063h)  -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple `loc` assignment with a condition:

string `"TRUE"`:

```
df.loc[df['Col_A'].eq('TRUE'), ['Col_B', 'Col_C']] = [1, 'SD']
```

boolean `True`:

```
df.loc[df['Col_A'], ['Col_B', 'Col_C']] = [1, 'SD']
```

output:

```
   Col_A   Col_B  Col_C
0   TRUE     1.0     SD
1  FALSE  1001.0  Valid
2   TRUE     1.0     SD
3   TRUE     1.0     SD
```

Comment: It doesn't work, like it runs but the result is the same as before, it is as if it didn't read the condition. Could it be because of the Col_A being a boolean type of format?

Comment: Yes, if you have a boolean the condition is different (you don't need to compare, just use the boolean directly), let me update

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying that from the start. That worked, I'm still not sure why the other methods didn't yield the same results but hey, since that works I'm all good. You think the rest of the methods didn't work for the same reason (boolean vs string type)?

Comment: Yes, this was probably the main issue ;)